# Swap doesn't work for the object attributes in Python?

Tags: python

I write the heap sort code is as follows:

What is interesting is

```
self.first, self.last = self.last, self.first
```

is not swapping the two values in the head and tail of the list `self.list`.

Why?

```
#heapsort
import pdb
class heap(object):
    def __init__(self, list):
        super(heap, self).__init__()
        self.list = list
        self.heapify()
        if self.list:
            self.first = self.list[0]
            self.last = self.list[len(self.list)-1]
    def length(self):
        return len(self.list)
    def heap_node(self,i):
        large_i = i
        if 2*i+1<self.length() and self.list[2*i+1]>self.list[i]:
            large_i = 2*i+1
        if 2*i+2<self.length() and self.list[2*i+2]>self.list[large_i]:
            large_i = 2*i+2
        if large_i!=i:
            self.list[large_i], self.list[i] = self.list[i], self.list[large_i]
            self.heap_node(large_i)
    def heapify(self):
            for i in range(self.length()/2,0,-1):
                j=i-1
                self.heap_node(j)
    def sort(self):
        # pdb.set_trace()
        if not self.list:
            return []
        else:
            # self.list[0], self.list[len(self.list)-1] = self.list[len(self.list)-1], self.list[0]
            self.first, self.last = self.last, self.first 
            return heap(self.list[0:(self.length()-1)]).sort() + [self.list[len(self.list)-1]]

h=heap([1,3,2,5,4])
print h.list
print h.sort()
```

Comment: Side note... it's really not a great idea to name a variable `list`, since that's already a Python builtin.

Comment: I suggest you change the `length` method to be a `__len__` one so that you can call `len(myHeap)` and get the length that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.first` and `self.last` are just copies of the data contained in `self.list[0]` and `self.list[-1]`. You need to assign to these values directly:

```
self.data[0], self.data[-1] = self.data[-1], self.data[0]
```

Using negative array indices causes Python to look at the list from the end. Also, I suggest using a name such as `data` instead of `list` to lessen the chances of shadowing the builtin name `list`.

Answer (score 2):

it should be  `self.list[0], self.list[-1] = self.list[-1], self.list[0]`

`self.first` and `self.last` are just variables containing first and last value from the `self.list`, changing them doesn't change `self.list`